# Mouse buttons - switch primary and secondary buttons on one computer changes them on another

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, mouse

I have two Windows 8.1 computers with USB wired mice (1 for each computer).  The computers are only connected via an internet router (1 wired, 1 wireless).  If I change the primary and secondary buttons of the mouse on one computer (Control Panel: Mouse:) they also change on the other computer.  Any idea why and how I prevent this?  I've not noticed this interactivity with anything else.

Comment: I have a feeling microsoft saves your settings to your ms live account (may be called something different - I don't use windows) and apply them for all computers you log in on. Similar to the way that signing into Google Chrome will load bookmarks and plugins on a previously unused browser.

Answer (score 1):

(expanded from comment)

I have a feeling microsoft saves your settings to your ms live account (may be called something different - I don't use windows) and apply them for all computers you log in on. Similar to the way that signing into Google Chrome will load bookmarks and plugins on a previously unused browser.

From [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/microsoft-account-tutorial) (my emphasis):

> When you sign in to your PC or device with a Microsoft account, you can get apps from the Windows Store, back up all your important data and files using free cloud storage, and **keep all your favorite stuff**—devices, photos, friends, games, **settings**, music, and so on—up to date and **in sync**.